# KMeans Cluster Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

We have done KMeans clustering with k=3 Clusters on dataset having 4 features,and have plotted the Centroid coordinates of each cluster with the input features. We want to focus on a cluster and try to figure out which feature is contributing more to a particular cluster with respect to other features. We do the same for other clusters too.

For e.g. lets assume we have clusters c1, c2 & c3 with features f1, f2, f3 and f4. The centroids for the clusters are for e.g. 
C1,C2,C3 respectively with corresponding features f1,f2,f3,f4

```
     f1           f2         f3          f4
```

C1=[-2.02746249  2.10961828 -0.57917217  1.687631  ]

C2=[ 0.63967987 -0.55768793  0.76387423  0.26527411]

C3=[-0.38727624  0.18714381 -1.27291271 -1.27310585]

Can we infer that for cluster 1 since the centroid for feature2(f2) is highest so can that be considered as the most significant/contributing feature for that particular cluster, similarly for cluster 2 centroid for feature3(f3) is highest so can that be considered as the important feature for cluster 2.

Thanks

Comment: (Also in reply to [your comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398499/kmeans-cluster-analysis#comment746508_398500):) What do you mean by "which feature is contributing more to a particular cluster with respect to other features"? I can't interpret this any other way than "which feature contributes most to *discriminating* between clusters", which [Peter Flom answered perfectly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/398500/1352).

Answer (score 2):

No.

First, you'd have to define exactly what you mean by "most significant/contributing" but, intuitively, the thing that is most distinctive about a cluster is the thing where it is most different from other clusters.

Assuming all the features are standardized, we can look at differences between clusters on features by subtraction. Then wee can say that F1 and F2 distinguish C1 from C2 more than F3 and F4 do, but that F4 distinguishes C1 from C3 best, while F3 distinguishes C2 from C3 best.

But even that is not really right, because the clusters are formed based on distances that are computed on all four features at once.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but we are looking for important features within the same cluster but not among the Clusters.

Comment: Within each cluster, all features are equally important, given that distances are computed as sum-of-squares.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense. "important within a cluster" doesn't really mean anything.